# Can't apply reduce on array of numbers or nulls

Tags: typescript

I was playing with TS, here I just wanted a method that would sum numbers (assuming some elements could be `null` too, so those would be ignored):

```
let squareNumbers = (numbers: (number | null )[]): number => {
    return numbers.reduce((accumulator,c)=> {       
        return c === null ? accumulator : accumulator+c
        }, 0);

}

console.log(squareNumbers([1,2, null, 4,5]))
```

Expected output: 12

But I get error:

> Type 'number | null' is not assignable to type 'number'.   Type 'null'
> is not assignable to type 'number'

Not sure about what it is complaining? I thought I had some checks for that like `c === null`  and using `0` as `accumulator`'s initial value.

---

**Update**: Ok I think that complain was about the type of what I was returning from main function, after changing above code to this:

```
let squareNumbers = (numbers: (number | null )[]) => { // removed return type
    return numbers.reduce((accumulator,c)=> {       
        return c === null ? accumulator : accumulator+c
        }, 0) ;    
}
```

Now it complains `accumulator` can be `null`. But shouldn't it deduce that it can't be `null` in my example?

Comment: This might actually be an issue with how the function is typed. It gets the `accumulator` type from the generic type of the array that you pass - in your case `number | null`. The default value seems to be completely ignored.

Comment: @MikeS. yeah that's my point, I was expecting it to pay attention that I used 0 as initial value

Comment: the issue is probably be the type definition of `reduce(cb: (acc: T, c: T) => T, initial: T)` which makes typescript find a common `T` type that works for both the number `0` and the `number | null` elements in your array. If you manually narrow / define that type for `initial` it works. There's a second definition that maps from `T` to another `U` but I guess that isn't used because `number | null` already works as `T`

Comment: To add to @zapl 's comment, you could simply narrow the generic type of `reduce` to `number` and the accumulator will have the right type. The current value will still have the type of the array, so checking for `null` is still required.

Comment: `reduce<number>` works, see https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEMFcBcHsFtzQJYGNwBsME9TIHYBmApgE6nEAmocoARsQFAigWWSrEAU6Wd4qANaF8ALlBcADhQBuyWJADOANUyRi4gCoAaUKkjli+aKozqtu-YeMBJfJWIAPcfkjwGpXeHLhsWgNoAugCUoAC8AHygOnj4yCiYpubRwVoA3MxgdDCg2Aqg+MRUmaxUHMQAPACqETyYGPxCIuJSsvJKSRqgVZYGFMadFnp9RtB2Ds4Fbh5ePn7RQaGR3boE8ciJal1Vqd0ZGMTQoIoAjpDexABy02SK4RKu7rctjx6gAD5TWMGLLjek4SiAG9GKAwaVoAZ8FMnqRFAA6NjlCqvMi1LgCfTwSAYJCwTx6P6wj5fDBLYGg8FUiiQ0jQ1DhMJhUmgAD8EFQWJxeIB4kxbm5cABAGo9JSwQBfXQABmCGQlQA

Comment: @zapl  Not sure what you mean in your first comment, I had suspicion similar to Mike S. that it deduced from generic type of array, that type of accumulator is `number | null` isn't that what you mean?

Comment: I think that's what I mean :) See typescript playground. There are 2 overloads for reduce, one that has only a single `T` which would be `number | null` in your code but then fail with the error you get. And there's that definition with `U` that is used when you map (type-transform)  values of T to values of U inside the callback. It should have been selected with `T = number | null` and `U = number` but it wasn't because (that's the part I don't really know). `reduce<number>` or `accumulator: number` forces typescript to use it because the simple definition no longer works.

Comment: I ctrl clicked on a `reduce` function within vscode, which lead me to the d.ts file used in my project that has the definition of `Array<T>`. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/0ac12bbe7a410238ca992a42f41816a97f6906f4/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1447 should be it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript [defines](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/0ac12bbe7a410238ca992a42f41816a97f6906f4/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1447) arrays as

```typescript
interface Array<T> {
    ...
    reduce(callbackfn: (previousValue: T, currentValue: T, currentIndex: number, array: readonly T[]) => T, initialValue: T): T;
    reduce<U>(callbackfn: (previousValue: U, currentValue: T, currentIndex: number, array: readonly T[]) => U, initialValue: U): U;
}
```

In your code, the `numbers` array (`numbers: (number | null )[]`) is `Array<number | null>` and `T` is `number | null`.

Typescript needs to check which overload of `reduce` you mean. It probably tries the first definition first and will see that there is no type violation. All parameters are `number | null`, or subtypes thereof, namely `null` or `number` or the type `0` which is a subtype of number.

So it selects

```
type T = number | null
reduce(cb: (accumulator: T, c: T) => T, initial: T): T
```

and then complains that you can't do `accumulator+c` because `accumulator` could be null.

What you want to use in your code is the other overload though that maps from the array's type `T` to any other type `U` during the reduce operation.

By calling it with

```
numbers.reduce((accumulator: number,
```

you create a case where the callback no longer accepts `number | null` in `accumulator`, so that overload is no longer valid. Instead it tries the other one and would find that

```
type T = number | null
type U = number
reduce(cb: (accumulator: U, c: T) => U, initial: U) => U
```

works without violation.

The other alternative is to explicitly define `U` by calling it as

```
reduce<number>((accumulator, c) => ..., 0)
```

The switch between those overloads usually works without specifying the type, but in this case you have types that happen to be too compatible to each other.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide type for the `reduce callback` as well

```js
let squareNumbers = (numbers: (number | null)[]): number => {
    return numbers.reduce((accumulator: number, c: number | null) => {
        return c === null ? accumulator : accumulator + c
    }, 0);
}
```

You can always do something like this in the callback

```js
let squareNumbers = (numbers: (number | null )[]) => { // removed return type
    return numbers.reduce((accumulator, c)=> {  
        if (accumulator === 2) {
            return null;
        }     
        return c === null ? accumulator : accumulator+c
        }, 0) ;    
}
```

That's why the compiler is complaining that `accumulator` could be `null`.

Comment: Please have a few words regarding the fix that you done.

Comment: I am not so much looking for solution but explanation why I was getting the error? Why was not it able to deduce that accumulator would never be null? I had specified 0 as initial value isn't it?

Comment: No compiler can't detect that, what if you assign null to the accumulator manually?. what if there is a condition that returns null in the callback?

Comment: no I meant in my code I am not assigning `null` to `accumulator` manually